# kdenlive - How to set rendered video orientation? Landscape or Portrait!

Tags: kdenlive

It's strange, but my rendered video is portrait oriented and I want landscape. I've been googling for two days with zero results. I know how to rotate a video using a rotating effect, but how to set the orientation of the **rendered video and/or preview video**?

I went to `project settings` and set to 16:9 but nothing.

These are my video project settings:

```
Frame size: 1920 x 1080 (16:9)
Frame rate: 25 fps
Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
Color Space: ITU-R 709
Interlaced : no
```

So, why my preview video is portrait, cropping my landscape clip?

[image]